# How can I change a column time attribute to AM and PM for the blade view?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-models

I have a table named `time_entries` and the column name is `time_start`.

I'm inserting `Carbon::now();` on it. The data stored in the column is `2021-08-26 09:51:37` and `blade.php` shows same result.

##### Model `TimeEntry`:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TimeEntry extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function getTimeStartAttribute($value)
    {
        return Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $value)->TimeString();
    }
}
```

##### Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\TimeEntry;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AttendanceController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $data = TimeEntry::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->paginate(2);

        return view('Admin.Attendance-History-page', compact('data'));
    }
}
```

##### Blade view:

```html
<tbody id="table_data">
    @foreach ($data as $punch)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $punch->user->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $punch->user->employee_id }}</td>
            <td>19 Feb 2019</td>
            <td>{{ $punch->time_start }} </td>
            <td>{{ $punch->time_end }}</td>
            <td>9 hrs</td>
            <td>
                <span class="badge bg-inverse-success">Perfect</span>
            </td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

I want to know how can I format the output from `2021-08-26 09:51:37` to something like `09:51:AM` in Blade?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What have you tried? It should work with the date() and strtotime() functions, just like it would in any PHP file.

Comment: no this is a php framework so we have to get form models

Comment: Yes, I know it's a framework, but you do know that you can use native PHP functions in frameworks as well, right? Just create a method in the model that returns the date you want in the format you want (using date() and strtotime()). When you ask a question here, don't just ask us to fix it for you without showing us that you at least made an attempt. We're here to help you sort out issues you might have with your attempt, not to write it all for you (which an answer to this would require us to)

Comment: thank you but this is my first project on laravel. i don't know to how to get data attribute form database to the models and the model to videw

Comment: But that's literally what the posted code does?

Comment: I'm explain this code get data form the database and show to the view call Attendance-History-page.blade.php. it show what is in the database exeat result but i what to change a particular data row attribute  form the model and sent it to the view.

Comment: Your `$data` variable contains a collection of `TimeEntry` models. In your foreach loop in the view, you're iterating through the collection so each `$punch` contains a single `TimeEntry` model. So if you add a method to that model that returns the data you want (the time in the format you want), you just call it with: `$punch->yourMethod()` in the view.

Comment: thank you my brother Mr.Magnus Eriksson it work thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a straight forward solution for this using the PHP `date()` method.

```
{{ date('h:m A', strtotime($punch->time_start)) }}
```

This will output `09:51 AM`

If you want to output `09:51:AM` then just add `:` after the `m` and remove the space, like so:

```
{{ date('h:m:A', strtotime($punch->time_start)) }}
```

Comment: Author can also take advantage of [`casting`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting), so it is automatic (no need to do `date(...)` everytime, author would be able just to do `{{ $punch->time_start->format('h:m:A') }}`).